# Chrome Extension - Saving the state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to code an adblocker

I ran into some issues with saving the state. So this is my code:

```
    $(".slider").click(function() {
        if( $("#checkbox").is(":checked") ){
            $("#onOroff").text("OFF");
            $(".slider").css({"background-color": "#C75052"});

        } else {
            $("#onOroff").text("ON");
            $(".slider").css({"background-color": "#50c878"});
        }
    }); // Switches it from On and Off


    var valueToBeSaved = document.getElementById('checkbox').value;

});
```

This is the blacklist:

```
    "*://*.port80adge.hit.gemius.pl/*",
    "*://*.youtube.com/*",
    ];

    var enabled = true;
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
            function(details) {
                console.log("blocking:", details.url);
                return {cancel: true};
            },
            {urls: blackList},
            ["blocking"]
        );
```

I have two separate files, one is for the script and other one is for the blacklist (because blacklist can become quite long).

I want to save the state of the app. I made a switch with input. I have seen examples of using chrome storage to save the state, but to be honest, I can't make the proper adjustments needed in order for it to work in my case.